# Create a bootable ISO with error

Tags: linux

I have copied a RHEL DVD content to my hard disk.  Now, I want to create a bootable ISO (/isolinux/isolinux.bin) by image burn.  However, it could not work and show the following error.

ISOLINUX 4.02 2010-07-21 ETCDisolinux: Image checksum eror, sorry...
Boot failed: press a key to retry..

Comment: Hi, i think the appropriate place to ask that is serverfault

Comment: But, try downloading it again, it seems something was corrupted while you burned the disc or downloaded the iso

Comment: have u used any tools like http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/  http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Answer (score 0):

You can not just copy the content of a dvd and expect it to behave as an img file.

Just download a bootable image and burn that to disc.